# Pulseeffect not working

Tags: sound

I have installed pulseeffects and been using it for a week until I installed butt and after that its no longer working. All my apps that uses audio it will show on pulseeffects application however there is no sound. Audio will only work if I disabled the app on pulseeffects. I have version 4.5.9.

I checked using this:
pactl list short sinks
0 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 48000Hz RUNNING
1 PulseEffects_apps module-null-sink.c s16le 2ch 48000Hz SUSPENDED
2 PulseEffects_mic module-null-sink.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED

and this:
pactl list short sources
0 alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 48000Hz IDLE
1 alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo module-alsa-card.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED
2 PulseEffects_apps.monitor module-null-sink.c s16le 2ch 48000Hz SUSPENDED
3 PulseEffects_mic.monitor module-null-sink.c s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED

is there any way that I can go back to using my pulseeffects?

Thanks in advance.